# Как добавить и выгрузить картинку из Ms Sql

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, angular

У меня есть БД, где есть столбец с картинками. Как вставить картинку в БД, а потом через какой тип данных её выгрузить в контроллер Asp .net, а потом уже в ангуляр. Насколько я знаю, то это тип данных byte[], но это в на стороне сервера, а как быть в Angular? Если даже поставить any, то картинки просто не загружаются.

БД:[image: БД]

Модель БД на стороне сервера:

```
public class Clothes

    {
        public int ClothesId { get; set; }
        
        public string VendorCode { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        
        public int Price { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Модель данных на ангуляре:

```
export class Clothes{
  vendorCode = "";

  name = "";

  image:any = [];

  amount = 0;

  price = 0;

}
```

Comment: а почему булеан?

Comment: Поправил на произвольный тип.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на стороне MS SQL Server надо получить данные в base64 из вашей колонки varbinary, где записаны картинки. Вот пример конвертации данных:

```
   select ClothesId, Image 
    from openjson(
        (
            select ClothesId ,Image 
            from Clothes
            for json auto
        )
    ) with(ClothesId int, Image varchar(max))
```

условия в выборку сами добавьте по конкретному id и тп.
для отображения в html нужно будет подставить полученную строку base64:
допустим, что

```
clothes.Image = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{clothes.Image}}" alt="Red dot" />
```